# React Native app crashes my iPhone when deployed in release mode

Tags: ios, react-native

I am in a sticky situation and would appreciate any advice. My app is pretty much complete
but when I am deploying it to my iPhone in release mode, my phone crashes when I try to hide the app. I mean, when you swipe up to go back to the home screen.

I have absolutely no idea what to do right now. it's only happening in release mode and it's giving me no error log while crashing so I don't even know where to look.

I don't know what code to show you guys so here's the whole project I guess:https://github.com/vivaanxr/YU-Food

Feel free to ask me to add any other additional details regarding this. This is my first project and kind of lost with this.

Comment: Does the phone crash or does your app crash?  Are you using TestFlight?

Comment: my phone goes black and then starts showing revolving loading screens and leaves me at the lock screen. I have not tried TestFlight yet, but i don't get how that could be helpful regarding this.

Comment: i think you should be using `@react-native-firebase/app` instead `firebase`. was there a reason for not using the react-native firebase packages?

Comment: I didn't want to import all the modules because I am only using one of them

Answer (score 2):

This is not the definitive solution to the problem, but should give you more information about what's happening.

Build to your device using Xcode. Then select Window > Devices & Simulators from the menu. Select your device and open the device's console. You can get additional information by reading the console while as the app crashes. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I have tried that but nothing seems to be showing up there. I have even installed sentry but even that isn't reporting anything